# Win7: sort icons in "desktop" popup/toolbar

Tags: windows, desktop, taskbar, sorting, popups

I've right clicked my task bar and selected *Desktop* in the *Toolbars* submenu. This now shows a *Desktop >>* button left to the tray area. When I click this button, a popup with my desktop icons opens allowing me to access my desktop icons without having to hide my application windows.

How can I configure in what order the desktop icons in the popup are sorted (I want them sorted alphabetically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click any of the item that comes out on the popup... then select sort by name...

Comment: Thanks, I've did not try it because I thought I would sort my desktop icons instead of those in the popup.

Comment: Hm, some icons are sorted correctly, others not - strange. For example "VMWare Player" is sorted before "Opera". Could it be that Windows sorts the all-user-icons and my-icons and then puts both sorted groups in the menu?