# How to alphabetize the Desktop Toolbar

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, desktop

Open the Desktop toolbar list down in the Windows 7 task bar.
Click the ">>" button to open the list.
The list of items (files and folders) on the Desktop are not in alphabetical order.
Is there a way to change this setting?

Comment: Right click and select "sort by name." This may not give you the results you are looking for though, as the items are still sorted by file type as well. You can also click "sort by name" on the folders and it will alphabetize the contents. This list behaves similar to File Explorer by grouping similar file types together.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/236014/win7-sort-icons-in-desktop-popup-toolbar

Answer (score 0):

I and many others use the toolbar in Portrait and on auto-hide; so that we can expand it to half the screen (max) and have lots of shortcuts available. If the toolbar is not really full and you click on a shortcut to sort them then the option is not available. First you must resize the toolbar so that there is not enough room to display all the shortcuts in the toolbar; only then will the list option become available. I cannot believe, well actually I can, that Microsoft have not fixed this failing after decades of user's complaints. And it still does not sort properly; It shows the shortcuts in the Desktop toolbar in 3 groups: system, then machine, then user shortcuts; and will not sort them all together.

It is well worth the effort to maintain your own toolbar, between installations, reins